# How to properly implement JButton in JFrame? It just takes up the whole screen

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, layout-manager

I am new at GUI making and I don't really get how to properly implement a JButton. So I've put it in but I can't seem to get it to not take up the whole window. I just want a small little button at the bottom of the window.

I've tried setbounds and setsize but neither seem to be working.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Menu extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private Container win;
    private Color color;
    private ImageIcon exportButton = new ImageIcon("export.png");

    public Menu(){
        super("MLA Formatter");
        JButton b1;
        win = getContentPane();
        win.setBackground(Color.white);
        b1 = new JButton("Export File");
        b1.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
        b1.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
//        b1.setBounds(500,900,100,100);
        b1.setSize(100,100);
        add(b1);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Menu window = new Menu();
        window.setBounds(200, 200, 1000, 1000);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: The placement and size of components added to a panel comes down to the layout of the panel and the constraint used to add it. See [How to Use Various Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html).

Comment: You've already been told how to use layout managers, complete with links -- why are you asking the question again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to demonstrate the options you have with below example (Here I have taken your code and minimized it to demonstrate my point.).

Here I've mentioned 4 options. You can uncomment the code under each option (one at a time) and run it and see yourself.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Menu extends JFrame {

  public Menu() {
    super("MLA Formatter");
    JButton b1 = new JButton("Export File");
    b1.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
    b1.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);

//Layout 1
//Default layout of JFrame content pane is BorderLayout.
//When we do not specify a constraint (like BorderLayout.SOUTH), default is BorderLayout.CENTER
//So, this is equivalent to add(b1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //add(b1);

//Layout 2
    //add(b1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

//Layout 3
    //setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    //add(b1);

//Layout 4
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    add(b1, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.SOUTH,
        GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10), 0, 0));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Menu window = new Menu();
    window.setBounds(200, 200, 1000, 800);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: [warning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire)

Comment: [warning 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54383362/jbutton-size-wont-change-is-there-a-reason-that-i-cant-change-its-size)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You either need to

1. Properly use your layout manager.(by default for JFrame, its BorderLayout)
2. Or set Layout to null.

In your constructor just add this:

```
setLayout(null);
```

Your constructor shall look like:

```
    public Menu(){
        super("MLA Formatter");
        JButton b1;
        setLayout(null); // add this line
        win = getContentPane();
        win.setBackground(Color.white);
        b1 = new JButton("Export File");
        b1.setBounds(500,400,100,100);  //changed this co-ordinates(900 will overflow)
        b1.setSize(100,100);
        add(b1);

    }
```

Though, i would suggest you to learn about using layout managers.